# SubTotal Query based on condition of other column

Tags: ms-access

I am creating a spare part management database in Microsoft Access. I have two table which are ItemTable and EntryTable. ItemTable holds information about each item with unique ItemID and EntryTable holds information of each items usage. I need to calculate the total stock left for each items based on the usage.

[image]

So as you can see, for the ItemID with 2, i need to calculate the total stock left based on the usage of In or Out of Status field.

If status is In then plus elseif status is Out then minus. Then total the stock of ItemID 2. Thus the total stock for ItemID 2 will be 3. I have figured out by total and group by for the ItemID but i cannot figure out the way to subtotal based on condition from other column.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select itemid,
  sum(iif(status = 'In', 1, -1) * quantity) as total
from entrytable
group by itemid
```

Comment: is it possible to link back the stock quantity values from the query to respective items to the ItemTable?

Comment: The result of this query, for the sample data that you posted, would be 2 rows: 1 for each of the itemids 2 and 3. How would they be linked to 4 entryids: 4,5,6 and 7?

Comment: guess i think i will just insert the fields from the ItemTable to the query in order to simplify the things rather than complicating too much. Thanks man!